# Unable to click on element using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

newbie here. I've been reading the site for a while as I'm still new to coding but hoping you can help.

I've worked my way through some tutorials/worked examples on web scraping and am looking at the website http://enfa.co.uk/

I am trying to open an instance of Chrome using chromedriver with selenium in Python and click on one of the sidebar options on the website called 'Clubs' - located on the left of the homepage.

I've navigated to the element that needs to be clicked and taken the xpath to use in my code (simple use of 'inspect' in the Chrome dev tools when hovering over the 'Clubs' link, then copying the xpath). My code opens chrome fine (so no issues with Chromedriver and that part of the project) but I receive an error telling me the object has no click attribute.

I've tried returning the object and it states my list has no elements (which seems to be the problem) but am unsure why... am I using the incorrect xpath or do some websites react differently i.e. won't respond to a click request like this?

I have run my code on other sites to check I'm utilising the click function and it seems to work ok so I'm a little stumped by this one. Any help would be great!

Code:

```
chromedriver = "/Users/philthomas/Desktop/web/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("http:enfa.co.uk")
button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[5]/td")
button.click()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sel.py", line 9, in 
    button.click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

[HTML of link I am trying to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lc4fZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_elements_by_xpath` returns list of all web elements that match the criteria. You have to use to `find_element_by_xpath` instead of `find_elements_by_xpath`.

Also, iframe are present on your page so you need to switch to that frame before you perform any action on it. Kindly find below ssolution which is working fine for me.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http:enfa.co.uk")

driver.switch_to.frame(2);
ClubsLink=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Clubs')]")))

ClubsLink.click()
```

**Output after clicking Clubs link :**

[image]
helpful link to locate element  :https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: This is perfect - thanks so much for the quick reply. I'll do further reading on iframe and look at the selenium link you have shared.

Answer (score 0):

Change `button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[5]/td")` to `button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[5]/td")`

`driver.find_elements_by_xpath` returns a collection of element, not a single one, hence you cannot click it.

You can find some details and examples [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html).